# Dynamically change values in a Python list?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to dynamically change values in a list.

Right now, I have:

```
sectors = ['MSCI ACWI/CONSUMER DISCR', 'MSCI ACWI/CONSUMER STAPLES', 'MSCI ACWI/ENERGY', 'MSCI ACWI/FINANCIALS', 'MSCI ACWI/HEALTH CARE', 'MSCI ACWI/INDUSTRIALS', 'MSCI ACWI/INFORMATION TECH', 'MSCI ACWI/MATERIALS', 'MSCI ACWI/METALS & MINING', 'MSCI ACWI/TELECOM SVC','MSCI ACWI/UTILITIES']
regions = ['MSCI NORTH AMERICA', 'MSCI EUROPE', 'MSCI PACIFIC', 'MSCI EM LATIN AMERICA', 'MSCI EM EUROPE', 'MSCI EM ASIA']
```

Now, I want to create new lists derived from `regions` and `sectors` such that I have something like:

```
regions_CONSUMER DISCR = ['MSCI NORTH AMERICA/CONSUMER DISCR', 'MSCI EUROPE/CONSUMER DISCR', 'MSCI PACIFIC/CONSUMER DISCR', 'MSCI EM LATIN AMERICA/CONSUMER DISCR', 'MSCI EM EUROPE/CONSUMER DISCR', 'MSCI EM ASIA/CONSUMER DISCR']
regions_CONSUMER STAPLES = ['MSCI NORTH AMERICA/CONSUMER STAPLES', 'MSCI EUROPE/CONSUMER STAPLES', 'MSCI PACIFIC/CONSUMER STAPLES', 'MSCI EM LATIN AMERICA/CONSUMER STAPLES', 'MSCI EM EUROPE/CONSUMER STAPLES', 'MSCI EM ASIA/CONSUMER STAPLES']
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
regions_CONSUMER_DISCR = [x+'/CONSUMER DISCR' for x in regions]
regions_CONSUMER_STAPLES = [x+'/CONSUMER STAPLES' for x in regions]
```